# Estimate the Lift impact on overall audience in A/B test

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, ab-test

I am performing an **A/B test** analysis on two cohorts **tests** vs. **control**. I observed a positive lift of **1.5%** (lift in new downloaders) between the test and control.
The total audience in my A/B test was **25000**, i.e.,(12500 in the test vs 12500 in control).
Now I want to calculate the overall lift on my whole audience, which is 200k, out of which on 25K audience, I ran an A/B test.
I want to calculate the lift for the overall audience. What should be the correct approach to this?

Comment: Assuming your A/B test samples were randomly selected, wouldn't their results be representative of the whole? If not, why not?